# How to decide if a limit resulting $\infty$ is $+ \infty$ or $- \infty$ ??

Tags: calculus, limits

So I've just started to learn about limits and I have a doubt.. Well this is the limit that I've done:

$$\lim_{x\to -1}  \frac{-5}{(x+1)^2}  = \frac{\lim\limits_{x\to -1}(-5)}{\lim_\limits{x\to -1}(x+1)^2} = \frac{-5}{0} = \infty$$

I hope it is right. But the result of this limit is $- \infty$ and the chart I had to use for  the quotient property for my result, which is $n<0/0$ is just $\infty$. I don't know how to get $- \infty$ at this point. Could someone be so kind to explain it to me please? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You can't divide by zero!

Comment: Yes I can, because it's a limit.

Comment: Nope. You can never divide by zero, even in a limit.

Comment: The idea of a limit is that the denominator becomes very, very close to $0$, but never zero itself. We are interested in what the function does in the neighbourhood of $-1$, but not in $-1$ itself, as this can give us misleading information. In the neighborhood of $-1$ the denominator is close to zero, and therefore the fraction explodes. The denumerator is always positive, so the minus sign indicates that the function will explode to minus infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator $(x+1)^2$ is always non-negative. When $x$ tends to $-1$, since the denomiator is slightly larger than zero, while the numerator is negative, the limit diverges to negative infinity.

Answer (score 4):

To decide the sign of the $\infty$ consider e.g. $$\lim _{x \to 0^+} \quad \frac{1}{x}$$
i.e. $x$ tends to zero via positive values. Everything is positive and the value of $\frac{1}{x}$ simply increases. i.e. $\frac{1}{x} \to \infty$

Consider $$\lim _{x \to 0^-} \quad \frac{1}{x}$$
i.e. $x$ tends to zero via negative values. Now $\frac{1}{x}$ is negative but gets more and more negative i.e. $\frac{1}{x} \to -\infty$

Your case is essentially $-5/x^2$ and $x^2$ is never negative.

Comment: This is clear enough. Good job.

Comment: I undestand the example but.. In my case do I simply have to notice that a negative number over a positive number gives always a negative number?

Comment: @musicinmyheart yes, in the same way you'd recognise a negative number multiplied by a positive number is a negative number

Answer (score 3):

Simply note that:$$f(x)=\frac{-5}{(x+1)^2}<0 \quad \forall x\neq-1$$